# Block watch videos onYouTube

Tags: youtube, watch

My videos are on youtube but I want to put on my website but it does not want the people can watch on you tube, pro it must disable the Watch on you tube option. Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to disable "Watch on Youtube" link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638734/possible-to-disable-watch-on-youtube-link)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question but you can try by checking the "Authorize integration" option in Advanced options... ;-)