# YouTube Video Player On Website Only

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, video-player

Is there a way to have a YouTube video player on your website that does not allow the user to open the video on YouTube?

Here is my scenario, I have a website users login to. I want them to be able to view the videos, but not share or get the video link. I would like to setup the videos as unlisted on YouTube, so I can share the link with certain people if needed.

So basically I need a way to disable the "Watch on YouTube" option in the video player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new YouTube video player does not allow you to block the user from clicking on the video and going to YouTube to watch it. Even with extensive testing of different parameters (modestbranding=1&title=&.... many other things). I finally just got an account with JW Player and uploaded the video there. Their player does allow you to keep the video in the player and not allow the user to get access to the clip from getting the URL of the original.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638734/possible-to-disable-watch-on-youtube-link), all you need to do is add `&modestbranding=1` to the end of your embedding url.