# How to get instagram video in my website?

Tags: javascript, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm using instafeed.js

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
        userId: 'XXXXXXXXX',
        get: 'user',
        accessToken: 'XXXXXXXXX',
        resolution: 'standard_resolution',
        target: "instafeed-container",
        limit: 30,
        template: '<div class="col-xl-4 mb-4 gallery"><a href="{{image}}" title="{{caption}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" alt="{{caption}}" class="img-fluid" /></a></div>',
        sortBy: 'most-recent',
    });
    feed.run();
```

Not getting my instagram page videos. Thank You!

Comment: Hi @Amol - there's lots of great answers already on Stack Overflow - like this previous one which perhaps does what you want - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48958185/15310387.  If this is exactly you question - please flag your question as a duplicate, otherwise please provide more information on what you are missing / having trouble with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to disable "Watch on Youtube" link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638734/possible-to-disable-watch-on-youtube-link)